# I am getting an error as 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Profile' what does that mean and how to solve it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, error-handling, django-forms

Guys I am having an issue using django since I am newbie and learning right now and making a temporary project of blog where I am having a Profile page and there I want to insert an image and just of checking I am using shell and trying to find out url of the image (in my own laptop)
but I am getting an error "QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Profile" I am also attaching a image for your reference

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

So I have attached my image links above please take a look and please solve this issue as I am not able to learn ahead.
I am also providing you the code which I am writing in my shell :-

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User                             
In [2]: user = User.objects.filter(username = "varun")                          
In [3]: user                                                                    
Out[3]: <QuerySet [<User: varun>]>
In [4]: user.profile
```

This gives me the result as :- ***'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'profile'***

Comment: Please ignore ** in the code section above

Comment: A `QuerySet` is a *collection* of objects, so you can see it as some sort of list of  `User`s, it can contain zero, one, or more `User`s, hence it indeed makes no sense that it has a `.profile` object. You can use `User.objects.get(username='varum')` to obtain a `User` object.

Comment: Ohh thanks for helping me sir !! awesome explanation by you and saved lot of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're filtering a collection of objects and returning a collection that just so happens to have only one object in it.

```
user = User.objects.filter(username='varun')
// <QuerySet [<User: varun>]>
```

Trying to access user.profile would be similar to trying access the following

```
arr = [{ 'name': 'Varun'}]
arr.name
// It is a collection so you have to choose the element first to be returned and then try to access the property `name`.
```

What you want to do is the following which will return a singular User object

```
user = User.objects.get(username='varun')
user.profile
```

Comment: @Varun I'm glad to hear it. Please mark as answer for me. That would be awesome!

Comment: ya I will it still need 2-3 mins to mark it. Can you please upvote my question! I know its silly but I am a newbie!